# PHP String Parsing Strip *First* enter/return space from form textarea

Tags: php, string, whitespace, return, space

How do you strip *the first* (before any visible text) enter/return space from text taken from a variable (submitted from a textarea)?

Comment: quote kgb "the fact that it doesn't work might mean that the chars you are trying to delete are not really new line chars"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ltrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) removes only whitespaces *before* the text. you can put an array of additional chars you dont need into the second argument.

```
$userinput = ltrim($userinput, $charsYouDontNeed);
```

the fact that it doesn't work might mean that the chars you are trying to delete are not really new line chars

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$str = str_replace("\n\r", '', $content);
```

Note: If you want to convert newliness to `<br />`, use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) instead.

Note also that `"\n\r"` is for Windows systems, it is `\n` on unix/linux.

**Update:**

Try this regex:

```
$str = preg_replace(/[\n\r{2,}]+/, "\n", $content);
```

Comment: sorry - meant to say the first whitespace.. for example, when user accidentally presses enter a few times before actual visible text entry

Answer (score 2):

```
$userinput = trim($userinput)

trim() works for followings, though you can strip some of those giving a char list
    * " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
    * "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
    * "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
    * "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
    * "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
    * "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[\n\r{2,}]+/', "\n", $content);
```